# Disable woo commerce image zoom + lightbox

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently trying to remove the product zoom on all product pages. I do not need the lightbox. I do understand that there is an option to disable the lightbox in woocommerce settings but even so a user is still able to click on the image only to be redirected to the larger version of the image.

Is there anyway to edit the woocommerce php files so that the above is solved?

Comment: Did you check http://docs.woothemes.com/document/image-zoom-2/

Answer (score 2):

add the below lines of code in your functions.php if you are using version 3.0 or above

```
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can edit this file and remove the link

```
woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-image.php
```

(You can access the file by going to Plugins -> Editor and then choose WooCoomerce in the dropdown menu, then find the file.)